# RxJS: Emit the initial value before Delay

Tags: angular, rxjs

If I use `delay()` function like this, it emits data only after a time delay :

```
const TIME_DELAY = 5000;
return new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(res);
}).delay(TIME_DELAY);
```

But I need to initially emit the data, then emit it every TIME_DELAY milliseconds. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirements, `timer` does exactly that. Something like:

```
return timer(0, TIME_DELAY).pipe(
  map(() => res)
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-v7auxo?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of [timer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) function that allows you to specify initial delay (0 in your case), and then the interval in which the emissions repeat.

For example: `const stream$ = timer(0, TIME_DELAY);`

If you need to cast the result to another value or observable, you can add pipe and `map` or `switchMap` (in case of observable) operators.
For example:

```
const stream$ = timer(0, TIME_DELAY)
 .pipe(map(() => 'some value'));

// or
const stream$ = timer(0, TIME_DELAY)
 .pipe(switchMap(() => anotherObservable$));
```